# Open another class via button push as a display panel

Tags: java, swing, class, dialog

Basically I'm trying to open my porttest.java class via a button push in my main program.

I thought their might be a way to do it via frame.add(porttest) but that didn't work.

Here is my porttest.java code.

```
package Random;
import gnu.io.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;


public class porttest {
    private Enumeration ports = null;
    private HashMap portMap = new HashMap();
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;
    private JComboBox comboBox;
    public porttest() {
        initialize();
        searchForPorts();
    }
      public void searchForPorts()
        {
            ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

            while (ports.hasMoreElements())
            {
                CommPortIdentifier curPort = (CommPortIdentifier)ports.nextElement();

                //get only serial ports
                if (curPort.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
                {
                    comboBox.addItem(curPort.getName());
                    portMap.put(curPort.getName(), curPort);
                }
            }
        }
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 442, 266);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        label = new JLabel("COM Ports:");
        label.setBounds(10, 130, 82, 14);
        panel.add(label);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setBounds(76, 124, 93, 26);
        panel.add(comboBox);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    porttest window = new porttest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Do I need to add some code in here to make it work?

all I want it to do is open in the middle of my main program so the user can set some settings then close the program. The only reason I'm doing it this way is because I can't seem to get a JComboBox to work in a Jmenu.

maybe theirs another way to open a dialog box with a JComboBox?

any help would be great.

Comment: Well, since `porttest` doesn't actually return anything or make any information available to the caller, it's all rather useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic example of putting all your eggs into a single basket and then wondering why you end up with an omlet.

Java is OO language, you should break down your classes into areas of responsibility, building up the functionality through layers, which provides you with flexibility and the ability to change layers as you need.

For example.  Your `ports` class should do one job and one job only, get a list of `CommPortIdentifier`s

```
  public class Ports {

    public static List<CommPortIdentifier> listCommPorts() {
      List<CommPortIdentifier> listOfPorts = new ArrayList<>(25);
      Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

      while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier curPort = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();

        //get only serial ports
        if (curPort.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
          listOfPorts.add(curPort);
        }
      }
      return listOfPorts;
    }

  }
```

Then, you need some way to load these ports and displaying.  Not having the library you're using, I assumed the worst and assumed that this method would take time to run (or could potentially block), so I used a `SwingWorker` to do the actually loading...

```
  public class LoadPortsWorker extends SwingWorker<List<CommPortIdentifier>, Object> {

    @Override
    protected List<CommPortIdentifier> doInBackground() throws Exception {
      return Ports.listCommPorts();
    }

  }
```

Next, we need some way to display them.  Yes, you can use a `JComboBox`, but you also mentioned that you wanted to use menu items...

```
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Ports");
    LoadPortsWorker worker = new LoadPortsWorker();
    worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        LoadPortsWorker worker = (LoadPortsWorker)evt.getSource();
        switch (evt.getPropertyName()) {
          case "state":
            switch (worker.getState()) {
              case DONE:
                try {
                  List<CommPortIdentifier> ports = worker.get();
                  ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
                  for (CommPortIdentifier port : ports) {
                    JRadioButtonMenuItem mi = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(new PortAction(port));
                    bg.add(mi);
                    menu.add(mi);
                  }
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException exp) {
                  exp.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
      }
    });
    worker.execute();

    JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    mb.add(menu);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
    frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
```

This makes a `JMenu` called "ports", into, it creates a series of `JRadioButtonMenuItem`s, one for each port and adds them to the "ports" menu.  Each port menu item is added to the same button group, meaning that only one can be selected.

To make life easier, I've used a `Action` to wrap the `CommPortIdentifier` into a nice simple package...

```
  public class PortAction extends AbstractAction {

    private CommPortIdentifier port;

    public PortAction(CommPortIdentifier port) {
      this.port = port;
      putValue(SELECTED_KEY, false);
      putValue(NAME, port.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      // Do what ever you want to do with the port...
    }

  }
```

In this example, I added the "ports" menu directly to a `JMenuBar`, but you could as easily add it to another `JMenu` and create a sub menu.

Also, using this basic concept, you could also populate a `ComboBoxModel`, `ListModel` and even a `TableModel`...

Take a look at [How to use menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), [How to use actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [Worker threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: thanks for the help, but I'm having issues testing this either the catch exception has an error, or the (CommPortIdentifier port : ports) has an error on ports saying that it needs to be initialized, so I tried it again and next time no errors but when I Click on ports menu nothing happens

Comment: Either } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException exp) {
                  exp.printStackTrace(); or for (CommPortIdentifier port : ports) {

Comment: There was a mistake at the bottom of `public static List<CommPortIdentifier> listCommPorts() {`, which read `return listCommPorts();` which would have set up recursive method call which would eventually fail in a `StackoverFlowException`.  I've updated the example and tested it

Comment: Thanks works now:) it does list the COM ports twice though but I'm sure I can figure out what's causing that

Comment: Before you add the JRadioButtonMenuItem's to the JMenu, you could try removing all the elements (JMenu#removeAll I think)

Answer (score 2):

You state:

> I thought their might be a way to do it via frame.add(porttest) but that didn't work.

Or rather:

```
frame.add(new PortTest());
```

And do you know why? Becauase the porttest doesn't extend any component or have a component field that can be used in this way. I'm going to suggest that you gear your GUI classes towards creating JPanels, which can then be placed into JFrames or JDialogs, or JTabbedPanes, or swapped via CardLayouts, wherever needed. This will greatly increase the flexibility of your GUI coding.

Other suggestions:

- Avoid `null` layouts and `setBounds(...)`. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
- Instead you're far better off learning about and using the layout managers. You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).
- To help us now and to help yourself in the future, please edit your code and change your variable names to conform with Java naming conventions: class names all start with an upper-case letter and method/variable names with a lower-case letter.